# How can I represent authorization bearer token in YAML

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, hashicorp-vault, aws-secrets-manager, cyber-ark

I have generated the access token and placed in below mentioned mount path and this token need to be included in the Authorization header when making a request against the retrieve secret endpoint.

How can we achieve it in yaml scripting

```yaml
volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /run/test
    name: conjur-access-token
    readOnly: true
```

Comment: So this token needs to be used by browsers requesting your app or is it your app that needs to send this when making a request to some other server?

Answer (score 1):

This question is referencing CyberArk's [Conjur Secrets Manager](https://conjur.org)'s [Kubernetes authenticator](https://docs.cyberark.com/Product-Doc/OnlineHelp/AAM-DAP/Latest/en/Content/Integrations/k8s-ocp/cjr-k8s-authn-client.htm). It uses a sidecar authenticator client to keep an authenticated session token for Conjur's API refreshed in a shared volume mount with an application container running within a Kubernetes pod. This allows the application container to request secret values Just-in-Time (JiT) from the Conjur API with a single API call.

There is a file located at `/run/test/conjur-access-token` (according to the manifest snippet you provided) that contains the authenticated session token to use to connect to the Conjur API. Your application container needs to read `/run/test/conjur-access-token` and use it in the Authorization header as a Token-based authorization. To use `curl`, this would look like:

`curl -H "Authorization: Token token='$(cat /run/test/conjur-access-token)'" https://conjur.example.com/secrets/myorg/variable/prod%2Fdb%2Fpassword`

Where:

- `/run/test/conjur-access-token` is the path to the shared volume mount of the application container and sidecar Kubernetes authenticator client.
- `conjur.example.com` is the Base URL for your Conjur Follower in the Kubernetes cluster (or outside, if that's the deployment method).
- `myorg` is the organzation account configured at the time of Conjur deployment and configuration.
- `prod%2Fdb%2Fpassword` is the URLified secret variable path in Conjur. This would be referenced otherwise as `prod/db/password` but since forward-slashes are part of URL/URI, we need this URLified to `%2F`.

Answer (score 0):

If the file containing your token in the mount path is called `token`, then you can simply do (assuming that you use curl):

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /run/test/token)" ...
```